# Catch errors from New-WebServiceProxy in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling

I would like to use New-WebServiceProxy in my PowerShell script. I need more than one service to be up and running before continuing, but for some reason I cannot programatically catch the WebException and quit the script at this point.

Example:

```
$ws_uri = "http://localhost/no_service"
$status = "not run"

try {     
    $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $ws_uri -UseDefaultCredential 1
    $status = "The service is up and running."
} catch {
    $status = "The service is down"    
}

Write-Host Status of first web service
Write-Host $status


$ws_uri = "http://www.soapclient.com/xml/SQLDataSoap.WSDL"
try {     
    $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $ws_uri
    $status = "The service is up and running."
} catch {
    $status = "The service is down"    
}

Write-Host Status of second web service
Write-Host $status
```

Instead of entering the exception part, I only get an error in the PowerShell window like this:

```
PS C:\test> .\test.ps1
New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
At C:\test\test.ps1:5 char:14
+     $proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $ws_uri -UseDefaultCredential 1
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http://localhost/no_service:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
Status of first web service
The service is up and running.
Status of second web service
The service is up and running.
```

I tried to be more specific with the exception using [System.Net.WebException], but that does not change anything.

Comment: Probably need `-ErrorAction Stop` or set `$ErrorActionPreference = ‘Stop’`

Comment: Thanks @DougMaurer. Both suggestions works perfect.

Comment: I've added an answer for the benefit of future visitors. Please click the check mark to accept. You can always change this later if a better answer is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell not all errors are terminating errors which are required to trigger the catch block. To make all errors terminating, you can either set `-ErrorAction Stop` on individual commands or for the whole session set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` prior to try/catch block.